# Why is Gitkraken client failing pull changes from remote repository on github?

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, gitkraken

Im using gitkraken desktop client on macOS for a few respositories, I have two ssh keys associated with 2 different github accounts. From the termnial I am able to pull and push changes to repositories with the specific keys associated with the accounts, but when I pull the changes using gitkraken it throwns me an error when using either of the ssh keys

[image]

[image]

I have my ssh keys stored in `~/.ssh/` and I made sure both keys are added to ssh-agent. My ssh config files looks like:

```
Host github.com-vib1240n
  HostName github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Host github.com-lprather
  HostName github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

I am unable to figure out why Gitkraken client is throwing me this error and unable to pull the changes using the client. I can pull the change through terminal and the changes and branches show up on the Gitkraken client.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably why you have a 2021 feature request: "[Support SSH/config file](https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/191565/support-sshconfig-file)"

GitKraken does not support/read the `~/.ssh/config` file, which is why you must define a GitKraken profile with its own SSH key associated to it. See "[Authentication SSH](https://help.gitkraken.com/gitkraken-client/authentication/)".

[image: https://help.gitkraken.com/wp-content/uploads/authentication@2x.png]

Comment: I have 2 profiles for the 2 different github accounts, I did add the respective keys for the profiles, but I am still running into the issue. Does this mean I would have to generate new SSH keys just for the Gitkraken client? @VonC

Comment: @VibhoreSagar It is better indeed to use dedicated keys for GitKraken, in order to help debugging this issue. Don't forget to register their public key to the right remote user profile SSH keys page.